# how create a schema for create a place on mongoDB use moongose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm need to create a schema to add restaurts and then show this places on a map on react. like

1-name place
2-author
3-lat
4-log
5-description
6- open hour

this is need to id user connect for now how create and show on the react app and react native app.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

you can following this code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const restaurtSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true, trim : true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  location: {
    lat: { type: Number, required: true },
    lng: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  creator: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("restaurt", restaurtSchema );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can 2dsphere index for save location of restaurant and it helps you find  nearest restaurant or calculate distance.

```
   const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const restaurtSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true, trim : true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  locationLongLat: {
        'type': {type: String, enum: "Point", default: "Point"},
        coordinates: {type: [Number], default: [0, 0]}
    }
  creator: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
restaurtSchema.index({'locationLongLat.coordinates': "2dsphere"});
```